# Ejecutar un store procedure dentro de un select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

tengo 2 tablas que son CLIENTE y CLIENTE_COMPRA_MENSUALES, en la tabla CLIENTE, tengo todos los clientes y en la tabla CLIENTE_COMPRA_MENSUALES tengo todas las compras que el cliente realizo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cliente con el Cod_Doc 10 en el año 2021 con el mes 1 realizo 2 compras y el año 2022 con el mes 2 realizo una compra.

Tengo que llenar el campo Valor Calcutable, el valor de este campo lo obtengo ejecutando un store procedure(no tengo acceso para ver este sp) mandando como parametros de entrada  el cod_Doc , AñoCompra y MesCompra, esto internamente obtendra todos los registro de valorCompra y me retornara el Valor Calcutable

```
declare  @valorCalcutable as decimal(12,5)
exec usp_ObtenerValorCalcutable 10 ,2021,1 , @valorCalcutable output
select  @valorCalcutable -- 3.21000 -- valor retornado
```

he llegado a llenar el campo valor Calcutable recorriendo con un ciclo while los clientes y otro ciclo while para la tabla Cliente_compras_mensuales pero esto consume mucha memoria y  tiempo.
Habra una forma de poder ejecutar el store procedure enviando los parametros sin utilizar el ciclo while

Comment: No, lo que estás haciendo es lo único que se puede hacer, a menos claro que puedas modificar la lógica del SP

Comment: Todas estas cosas que tardan mucho y son resúmenes se hacen sobre tablas históricas

Comment: No entiendo una tabla mensual que no es un resumen mensual

Comment: Que permisos tienes sobre la BD

Comment: que es o que indica o calculo es Valor Calcutable

Comment: No tiene sentido ejecutar un procedimiento mas de una vez, no son para eso

Comment: ¿El valor calcutable es solo la suma del valor de compra para ese código, mes y año? De ser así, no necesitas llamar al procedimiento almacenado.

Answer (score 0):

No. La única forma es modificando el procedimiento almacenado para que permita como parámetros un conjunto de datos, por ejemplo una tabla o un cursor.

Comment: el procedimiento almacenado ya permite los 3 campos de entrada, pero mi duda es todabia de como poder consumirlo , si hago un while a mi tabla compras_mensuales funciona porque es por cada interaccion, envio los parametros y me devuelve el valor calcutable , pero esto toma mucho tiempo

Comment: Ese es el problema. Debería permitir como parámetros 3 listas (puedes llamarle arreglos, arrays, tablas). De esa forma solo necesitas llamar una vez al procedimiento y los datos se pueden procesar todos de golpe sin tener que ir uno a uno con un bucle While.